# GetJson jquery doesn't run success action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using this code to make an Ajax request to a JSON file:

```
var queries = $("#myform").serialize();

$.getJSON("/files/json.php?" + queries,
   function(data){
      alert(data);
   }
);
```

But it returns no errors and the alert is not performed. The PHP files send data using the

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

And if I open the same query within direct URL it returns the JSON data, so the problem is jQuery.

The network tab shows:

```
json.php?(my queries parameters and values)
/files
GET
200
OK
application/json
jquery.js:9597
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `"/files/.php?"` This doesn't look right to me, are you sure it's the right path?

Comment: sorry just a typo, the path is correct, the status of the ajax call is 200

Comment: Check for any other errors in JS Console. That might prevent you from expected execution.

Comment: there aren't errors. Added the network response.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON output is valid? `As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently` you can check if it's valid here http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

var queries = $("#myform").serialize();

```
 $.getJSON("/files/json.php", queries,
  function(data){
   alert(data);
  });
```

Second parameter for getJSON is actually form data which you have to pass to the php page